# Of subgroups of subgroups of permutations in $S_{5}$ and conjugates.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, permutation-cycles

Let $H= \langle a,b \rangle$ be the subgroup of $S_5$ generated by the two permutations:
$a=(1\,4\,5\,2)$ and $b=(1\,3\,4\,2)$

$1.$ What is the order of the permutation $g=ab$?

$2.$ How many conjugates of $g$ are there in $S_5$?

$3.$ Prove that $\langle g \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

$4.$ Prove that the subgroups $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ are conjugated in $H$.

### My attempts

$1.$

I calculate $ab$:

$ab=(1\,4\,5\,2)(1\,3\,4\,2)=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$

Since $ab$ is a $5$-cycle, its order is exactly 5.

---

$2.$

Let $c \in S_5$. The permutations $c$ and $g$ are conjugated if and only if they have the same cycle type, that is if and only if $c$ is a $5$-cycle. This means that we must have:

$c=(c_1\,c_2\,c_3\,c_4\,c_5)$, with $c_i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ for each $i=1,2,3,4,5$, with no repetitions.

For example, the permutation $(1\,3\,2\,5\,4)$ is acceptable, but $(2\,3\,4\,5\,3)$ is not. This makes me think that, chosen the first number, the second yields $4$ choices, the third $3$ choices, the fourth $2$ and the fifth $1$. This would make for $4!$ possible permutations, but I am not sure about this, since I do not really know how to exclude the fact that the first number can actually be chosen in $5$ different ways, which would make for $5!$ conjugates. But $|S_5|=5!$.

---

$3.$

Since $|g|=5$, it follows that $\langle g \rangle =\{g^p\,|\,p \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \}$.
The permutations $a$,$b$ are $4$-cycles, so they have order $4$ and $\langle a,b \rangle = \{a^tb^s\,|\,t,s\in\{1,2,3,4\} \}$

The subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ is normal in $H$ if and only if:

For each $g^p \in \langle g \rangle$ and $a^tb^s \in H$ for $p \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $t,s \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ , we have that

$(a^tb^s)^{-1}g^p(a^tb^s)=g^p$

I observe that $g^p=(1\,(1+p)\,(2+p)\,(3+p)\,(4+p))$, which is simply a consequence of the general properties of powers of $k$-cycles. Using the fact that, given $w \in S_n$ a $k$-cycle and $u \in S_n$ a permutation, we have that:

If $w=(w_1\,w_2\, ... \,w_k)$, then $u^{-1}wu=(w_1u\,w_2u\, ... \,w_ku)$.

I can write

$(a^tb^s)^{-1}g^p(a^tb^s)=(1a^tb^s\,(1+p)a^tb^s\,(2+p)a^tb^s\,(3+p)a^tb^s\,(4+p)a^tb^s)$

In order to conclude, I should be able to prove that the permutations $a^tb^s$ fix the numbers $1,(1+p),(2+p),(3+p),(4+p)$, which I do not know how to do.

---

I would be happy if you could help me with points $3.$ and $4.$, and of course, if I did any mistakes with the first two, please correct me.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: 2. There are 5 choices for first one, 4 for second one, etc., giving $5!$ (not $4!$). However, each cycle can be written in multiple ways: $(1,2,3,4,5)=(2,3,4,5,1)=(3,4,5,1,2)$, for instance. So you are overcounting and need to compensate.

Comment: $ab\neq(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$.

Comment: Also, what makes you believe that 
$$\langle a,b \rangle = \{a^tb^s\,|\,t,s\in\{1,2,3,4\} \}?$$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the same cycle can be written in $5$ ways, since different ways of writing it differ for a shift forward(or backwards), like $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)=(5\,1\,2\,3\,4)=(4\,5\,1\,2\,3)=(3\,4\,5\,1\,2)=(2\,3\,4\,5\,1)$. Does this mean that, for each cycle of the $5!$ I am considering, I have to subtract $4$?

Comment: @Servaes Here's how I calculated $ab$: $a$ sends $1$ to $4$ and $b$ sends $4$ to $2$, $a$ sends $2$ to $1$ and $b$ sends $1$ to $3$, $a$ fixes $3$ and $b$ sends $3$ to $4$, $a$ sends $4$ to $5$ and $b$ fixes $5$. This gives me the result, is it wrong? As for $\langle a,b \rangle$, am I perhaps confusing it with $\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle$ ?

Comment: Why woud you subtract $4$? If you think there are $m$ possibilities, but you counted *each* possibility $k$ times, does that mean there are $m-(k-1)$ possibilities?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right, I should actually divide $5!$ by $5$, instead of subtracting $4$, which is, more generally, dividing by the lenght of the $k$-cycle, is it not? This leads to $5!/5=4!$ possibilities.